# Can't disable wake-on-mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse, power-management, wake-up

I have Windows 7 installed on Asus M4A785-T MBO.

In BIOS, power settings are set to S3 (ACPI), and there is no S4 option.
Wake on (lan, keyboard, mouse, etc.) - all of these are disabled in BIOS.

When I put my computer into a hibernate mode, it shuts down the computer, but I am still able to start it up by moving the mouse. Win7's Hybrid sleep is not enabled, it's pure hibernate.

I don't think this should behave this way, but I was unable to find a resolution for the problem.

Where else can I look to disable wake-on-mouse?

Comment: Check out icelava's answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/183743/my-computer-wont-go-into-standby-or-hibernate

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. I didn't know that the windows settings can overrule the BIOS settings in hibernate.