# My computer won't go into standby or hibernate

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

I have a problem that I first noticed yesterday.  Whenever I would press the half moon standby button on my keyboard, my computer would go to sleep.  I also have a shortcut on my desktop configured to put my computer into hibernate.  But now whenever I try to put my pc in sleep or hibernate mode, my monitor goes black for a few seconds but then comes back on at the login screen.

I haven't installed or changed anything other than create a couple logical partitions in the hfs+ filesystem. (still in the process of trying to triple-boot)

Any help would be great, but for now I'm going to bed.  Will check back in the morning.

Comment: Are you plugged in via ethernet or are you using wifi?

Comment: Ethernet, just like I have been for months.

Answer (score 1):

Go look at your Device Manager, review the Power Management property tab of all your input devices and USB devices. Ensure the **Allow this device to wake the computer** option is not checked.

Comment: If you do that, I'm not sure that you'll be able to use your keyboard and mouse to wake up your computer...

Comment: Neither my mouse or keyboard are USB.  But good thinking and thanks for the warning.  I'm gonna try it now.

Comment: In all of the power management tabs, the "Allow this device to wake the computer" is grayed out.

Comment: @pattern86 it's a trade-off. Some of these dang input devices INSIST on maintaining active comms with the computer and preventing it from sleeping, like mine. T__T  I usually use the power button to wake the computer anyway.

Comment: Well I still have not figured out why I can't get into sleep or hibernate mode.  I'm not using a new keyboard or mouse and it's only been happening since two days ago.  Like I said the only changes I've made to ANYTHING were the two logical hfs+ partitions.  So do you have any more ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've had this issue, it's been because of a process in the background that's running that I didn't realize.  Check you taskmanager and make sure there aren't any processes that you don't recognize, or are taking up an unusual amount of resources.

Comment: This is pretty darn vague advice. Also, it processes shouldn't have the ability to unhibernate your computer just by running. They may set a wake timer or something like that that tells your computer to wake up at some point, but the processes aren't actually running while your computer is hibernating - so they can't wake your computer up. Can you mention what you actually have done to solve your problem in the past?